# Google fonts not displaying all the time

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I'm using the import thing in my CSS, like this

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One);
```

But the font doesn't load all the time. I'm still working on the CSS and refreshing periodically. Is it because of that? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of @import, you should add a link to your page by..

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then, add the `font` under the `body` element in your stylesheet using `font-family`.

**For Instance,**

```
body{font-family: 'Kite One', sans-serif;}
```

For further doubts, refer [here](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aKite+One).

It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues with Web fonts, you need to take a look at this

[Web Font Loader](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader)

The Web Font Loader is a JavaScript library that gives you more control over font loading than the Google Fonts API provides. The Web Font Loader also lets you use multiple web font providers. It was co-developed by Google and Typekit.